# How to run markup section's functions in the code section?

Tags: octobercms

For example with the rainlab translate plugin we can have this `{{ 'translatable text'|_ }}` I want to call them in the code section for dynamic title.

```
title = "Product" <-- I want to translate this
url = "/product"
layout = "default"
==
<section id="product-section">

</section>
```

Another example would be the blog plugin. I want the title to be set according the blog post title. I can use the `{{ post.title }}`  in the markup section.

```
title = "Blog Title" <-- I want to put the blog title here
url = "/blog-post/:slug"
layout = "default"
==
<section id="blog-section">
    <h1><span>{{ post.title }}</span></h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into code section (when you edit page in CMS).

```
function onEnd() {
    $this->page->title = $this['post']->title;   
}
```

According to this you can also write something like that:

```
$this->page->title = 'My page title';
```

I'm sorry for writing this solution now, but maybe it helps someone.